# How to avoid multiple login in different tabs of same browser

Tags: authentication, session-cookies

I have a JSF application, for which i wanted to restrict multiple login.

The actual scenario is if user1 login and click on registration link, the registration page will be displayed, in middle of filling the form.

If the same link is pasted in an other tab in same same browser, the system is allowing to work on both the tabs which is causing some problems.

Can any one suggest a way to avoid this.

Comment: This 'problem' is not related to any of the tags you use. It is in your login framework... And already an upvote? In only 6 views? Read [ask] on how to ask questions...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
boolean isNewSession = session.isNew();
```

to check whether the session is newely created. It returns false if the session is already present.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below attached. Hope it will work. While clicking on login set a key in Local Storage with some key (Example 'Y'). Place the below mentioned in common file which will be available in entire application. The below event will be triggered when the value of the Local Storage is changed. when the value is Y. call logout function. After login clear the Local Storage.

While clicking login - > CLEAR_USER_SESSION - > Y - This will logout other session's of the same application in the same browser as per the below code.

After login - change the value to N or empty - CLEAR_USER_SESSION  - > 'Y' or ''.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
  if (event.key == 'CLEAR_USER_SESSION') {
    var winUrl = window.location.href;
    var terminateSession = event.newValue;
    var homepage = "N";
    if (document.getElementById("empTrId")) {
        homepage = "Y";
    }

    if (terminateSession && terminateSession.trim() == "Y"
            && !winUrl.includes("loginAction.do?method=logout") 
            && !winUrl.includes("login.jsp") && homepage == "N") {
        logout();
    }
  }
});
```